# Format of source.yaml for Development Test for svn

Tags: ros, svn, pre-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm eager to take advantage of [Development Test](http://wiki.ros.org/regression_tests#Development_Tests) for my `svn` packages. In [its REP (137)](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0137.html#source-file), looks like `svn` is supported but what URL does `source.yaml` require?

I haven't seen any `svn` repositories listed in either [Groovy](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/groovy/source.yaml) nor Hydro. I assume it might be the path of the top directory of a package in either `trunk`/`branch`/`tag` (eg. in our case https://rtm-ros-robotics.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rtmros_common) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88391/format-of-source.yaml-for-development-test-for-svn/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SVN is still supported. The only difference is that the version information is encoded within the URL. SO the URL must point to a specific tag or branch.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0